# Bool tool artifacts when cutting holes

Tags: mesh

So I used a cylinder to cut holes through this mesh and I only noticed these artefacts later. How can I cut the holes without getting artefacts?

[image]

Comment: you need to add some edge loops, please show your wireframe or share your file

Comment: watch: [8 techniques of cutting holes in blender](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bc52fcrHvAA)